# How to scale x and y axis in qqnorm plot in R Studio?

Tags: statistics, rstudio

[qqnorm plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ0Qk.png)

I am plotting a qqnorm plot for a set of data in R. I want to scale x and y axis on same scale, i.e. x and y should start from same number. How can I do that? I have attached screenshot of qqnorm for my results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really a maths / statistics question but let's have a go...

Assume you have an assumed theoretical distribution F(X), take each observation of X = x(1), x(2) ... x(N), and work out the quantiles q these observations corresponding to in F(X), in order words q(i) = P(X < x(i)), so you have q = q(1), q(2) ... q(N).

If F(X) is a good distribution assumption for X, then the probability of getting a q(i) < 0.7 (let's say) should be 0.7, or P(q < q_hat) = q_hat. Therefore q follows a uniform distribution U[0,1].

If you now do a qq plot of q vs U[0,1] you will have axis that are in the bound [0,1]